# What is the difference between SqlDataReader SqlTypes and DbType typed accessors?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldbtype, dbtype

What is the difference between SqlDataReader SqlTypes and DbType typed accessors?

When is it more appropriate to use either?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to - do you mean, as an example, `GetDecimal()` vs `GetSqlDecimal()`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that is an example of what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code needs to be provider agnostic and work against multiple database systems, you should avoid using SQL Server specific functionality, your code should not reference `SqlDataReader` at all. It should use the neutral types such as `DbDataReader` and then only the `GetDecimal` method are available.

On the other hand, if you're happy to tie your implementation to SQL Server specifically, or you're already having to be implementation specific, then I'd suggest using the SQL Server specific accessors (e.g. `GetSqlDecimal`) and types, since they are more specifically aligned with the SQL Server data types.